# How to get sidebar to scroll and resize properly

Tags: css

It seems to be working except I can't get the entire menu on the right to show up on many displays. It seems to get cut off depending on your screen size.

```
 .mainDiv{ position: absolute; height: auto;}
.right{ position: fixed;  top: 400px; right: 200px; bottom:5px; background:none;padding-bottom: 60px;border:none; z-index: 5000;margin: 2em; height:100%; width:auto; verflow-y: scroll;}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6YDRB/

Any ideas?

Comment: Give us a jsfiddle, or at least the html. It's like you give us tire and ask what is wrong with your car.

Comment: So sorry! Here it is: http://jsfiddle.net/6YDRB/

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should define a `min-width`

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/6YDRB/2/

Answer (score 0):

What is happening is your `.right` `div` is `fixed` in position with `top:300px` and `right:100px` in your jsfiddle. Remove these static value and try with `%` if you are looking for responsiveness. Also set min-width as suggested by Sam.

Comment: Great. Please accept the answer and close this if your issue is solved.